# JUNIT AND JMOCKIT in STS

Tags: java, spring, junit, jmockit

I need to test this simple method using JUnit. This service will be returning all the users that will be present in a file. So its not hitting the database but a file.

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/allUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
           produces = 
           MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
           public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUserDetails() throws 
           Exception {

          List<User> allUserList = jdbcHive.getAllUserDetails();
          if (allUserList.isEmpty()) {
          return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
       }
       return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(allUserList, HttpStatus.OK);

     }
```

You can give any article or guide related. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to unit test this method or an integration test?

Comment: I need to unit test this method.

Comment: Can we use mockito

Comment: You want to test the response from reading a file or a mock object?

Comment: I want to test the response from reading a file.

Comment: @Rik If you want to unit test this controller method, you can use `@Spy` on the `jdbcHive` object and test.